# Launch lync chat from another mobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile, lync, lync-2010, lync-2013

To resume, I am developing a web application with Jquery mobile and I have a list of people  from the same enterprise. I was asked if by one click on a person, the application could launch a chat via lync.

I did some research and I found that : https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/what-is-lync-ucwa-api.
That API allow use to use Lync by adding C# code into the application, but my problem is that I have only HTML / CSS / JS for this project.

I think the only way for me would be to launch chat on the mobile or webversion of Lync from my application, do you know if it possible ? I can find an answer.

Thanks for your futur advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need IM and presence (i.e. no audio/video) then UCWA is ideal. It's a rest-based API, so there's no dependency on clients using C# to call it. As I remember, the documentation on the UCWA site is pretty good

Comment: I didn't see that UCWA was a restfull API, I will look how to communication with jquery but it seems possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but, i've an experimental java api which can communicate with Lync 2013 UCWA. [Here is the github page](https://github.com/mtorak/java-lync-client)

You are welcome to fork it.